# Where to start when making a dynamic website?

Tags: php, mysql, ruby, angularjs, node.js

I know HTML5 and CSS3, basics of JavaScript and jQuery, and I want to know what to learn next for back-end programming. Should I learn PHP or Ruby? How can Node.js help me? AngularJS? MySQL?

I'm confused and don't know where to start. Can somebody please explain?

Comment: Php is the better option for you!

Comment: Probably, but I would like to know more on the whole process of creating a  dynamic website :/. Thank you!

Comment: Questions seeking opinions this broad are off-topic (fortunately, or unfortunately, depending on your view). Please see the Help Centre for more information.

Comment: I suggest you drop Angular for the time being, since it requires an understanding of the client-server model and how HTTP works. Any of the server languages you mention are good. Node is a bit more complicated (it works on an event model) but is worth a go. PHP and Ruby and Python are often recommended for beginners. You may be interested in a PHP tutorial I wrote - see my profile.

Comment: So I can use Node.js to create database backed websites?

Comment: Yes, indeed, Node is fine. I don't think it is as suitable for beginners, for the reason already stated, but do try it all the same if you particularly wish to. (To address particular people here, please use @halfer or whatever username, otherwise people are likely to miss your message. It has tab completion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML, CSS, JavaScript and jQuery are used for front end development. For dynamic web development you got to get into server side too where you can take data from user and generate content depending upon the data. So start with a basic server side language - PHP and MySQL.

Once you get to know how server side works, then you can proceed on with other language. These are few [PHP based projects](http://marketinghacker.org/10-php-projects-for-beginners/) for beginners. Believe me when you are done with these PHP, server side and dynamic web development will be easy.

MySQL is your database. Install XAMPP (Windows) or LAMP (Ubuntu) to run Apache web server and connect to database using PHP.

Comment: no problem... enjoy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Codecademy has a rails application development track, which I mention because you tagged this post with ruby.